# Can we add alexa skills to a custom Alexa android app?

Tags: alexa-skills-kit, alexa-voice-service

I have created a sample android application with Alexa. I can able to get response from alexa server regarding weather, time, general questions etc. My requirement is

- Is it possible to control alexa enabled devices(light) through my application?

Comment: Did you use an amazon account to add alexa to your android app?

Comment: yes, of course. Added app from amazon developer console and get api_key. added it in the project

Comment: What happens when you say "Alexa turn on the light" ?

Answer (score 0):

Its possiblem, after a long research found that android skills can be added to custom alexa application. Logging to alexa account enables to link skills to android application